# If $a^2=b^2+c^2$, show that among those integers there is a multiple of 5 and a multiple of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

> If three positive integers verify: $a^2=b^2+c^2$, show that among them there is a multiple of 2 and a multiple of $5$.

Here's my attempt:

We denote congruence modulo $5$ by "$\sim$". We have shown that any square $x^2$ is of the form $x^2\sim 0$ or $x^2\sim \pm1$ (I have already shown that).  We show that $a^2,b^2,c^2$ cannot be of the latter form simultaneously. If that were the case, then $b^2+c^2 \sim \pm 2$, which contradicts the fact that $a^2\sim \pm1$. Therefore, at least one between $a^2,b^2$ or $c^2$ must be divisbile by $5$. Therefore, $a,b$ or $c$ is also divisible by $5$, since for any integer $x\sim 0 $ if and only if $x^2\sim 0 $.

We use the same argument to congruence modulo $2$, which we also denote by "$\sim$". Again by contradiction we suppose that all $a^2,b^2,c^2\sim 1$. Then, $b^2+c^2\sim 2$, contradicting the fact that $a^2\sim 1$. Using the same argument we arrive that some integer between $a,b$ or $c$ is multiple of 2.

Is this alright? Any more interesting proof?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Looks fine! ......

Comment: I've added the proof-verification tag.

Comment: A strong case can be made that one of $a$ or $b$ (and not just $c$) must be even.  But this proof looks good.  I'm sure a convoluted alternative "interesting" proof can be found but this seems interesting enough to me.  I don't see anything more efficient then modulo math to prove divisibility.

Comment: Yes, you can use $\bmod 4$ to show that one of $b$ or $c$ (as you have the identifiers) must be even.

Comment: It's fine.The usual notation  for congruence is $\equiv$. In MathJax, x^2 \equiv \pm 1\pmod 5 will give $x^2\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5.$... For "modulo 10" do not write \pmod 10  or you will get $\pmod 10$ . Write \pmod {10} to get $\pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is acceptable. I don't know of a "more interesting" proof, and I doubt one exists, since the statement is generally false for $2$ and $5$ replaced by other numbers (it only holds for $1,2,3,4,$ and $5$).